# Is it possible to use Protractor with a Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, protractor

Just what it says on the tin: is it possible to use Protractor test automation with a Angular app running under Cordova in IOS?

**Edit:** tried to fix the word-salad I made of the original post.

Comment: Title of the question is a bit confusing. Did you mean "use Protractor with a PhoneGap app?". And regarding the question: do you want to test it in IOS environment (like simulator) or it would be enough to just test html version of it? Question is very broad now.

Comment: protractor seems to be for angular, so, if your phonegap app uses angular, this should be possible.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov -- the title was mess.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://appium.io/, the Protractor docs even say how to use it https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/mobile-setup.md.  I'd tell you more but I'm just starting with it myself because I had exactly the same question as you!

Protractor docs guide you through both Android and iOS setup.

Comment: That discusses using Protractor with a mobile browser, not with a Cordova (hybrid native) app.

Comment: On the appium page it says "Appium is an open source, cross-platform test automation tool for native, **hybrid** and mobile web apps, tested on simulators (iOS, FirefoxOS), emulators (Android), and real devices (iOS, Android, FirefoxOS)."  The "hybrid" app they refer to is a Cordova/Phonegap app.  It uses a Selenium server just like regular webapp testing for Protractor.
I intend to follow the Appium instructions and do it myself.  It clearly supports Webdriver commands, and Protractor is a wrapper around Webdriver so seems like it ought to work.  Sorry for giving you an untested suggestion.

Comment: When I asked the question, I was having a lot of trouble getting Appium to work properly with Phonegap.  Turned out, we had a slight typo in the configuration.  Now I believe your suggestion will work.

Comment: How's it working for you?  I'm having a tough time with it myself.  It works on simulator and iOS physical device, but I get weird problems like:
expect(someSelector.isPresent()).toBeFalsy()
This seems to hang, like it's waiting for the element which isn't supposed to be there to show up.  For elements that are there, toBeTruthy() is working fine.  But checking the negative is not working right now.  And it was pretty tough going to get appium working with hybrid app in the first place.  Not sure I'd recommend it still.